# dropdown population with viewmodel asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am new in MVC. so when see code to understand then some time confusion occur. here i am giving a code. so please see the code first.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
}

public class OrderViewModel
{
        private List<ProductViewModel> _products;
        public int OrderNumber { set; get; }
        public List<ProductViewModel> Products
        {
            get
            {
                if (_products == null)
                {
                    _products = new List<ProductViewModel>();
                    _products.Add(new ProductViewModel { ID = 1, Name = "Ketchup" });
                    _products.Add(new ProductViewModel { ID = 1, Name = "Mustard" });
                    _products.Add(new ProductViewModel { ID = 1, Name = "Relish" });
                    _products.Add(new ProductViewModel { ID = 1, Name = "Mayo" });
                }
                return _products;
            }
        }
       public int SelectedProductId { set;get;}
}

public ActionResult Order()
    {
        OrderViewModel orderVM = new OrderViewModel();           
        return View(orderVM);
    }

@model ORderViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <p> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedProductId , new SelectList(Model.Products, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select Product--")
  </p>
}
```

my question is can i place this code `public int SelectedProductId { set;get;}` in `ProductViewModel` instead of `OrderViewModel`.

if it is possible then what to change in code and in view html ?

Comment: No, `SelectedProductId` needs to be in `OrderViewModel` so you can select a product for the order.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Comment: And `new SelectList(Model.Products, "Value", "Text")` needs to be `new SelectList(Model.Products, "ID", "Name")` because `ProductViewModel` only contains properties `ID` and `Name` (not `Value` and `Text`)

Comment: i have not checked the code i posted. does the code i posted will work or need change to get it work. if change require then please tell me which line need to change. thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have seen your dotnetfiddle code. what to add in code to show entered order no and selected product name and id? would u mind to add some to show entered order no and selected product name and id after form submit.

Comment: @Mou, Not sure I understand what your asking. The form in the fiddle does include a textbox to enter the order number. When you post back to public ActionResult Index(OrderViewModel model) then model.SelectedProductId contains the ID of the selected product. And a <select> only posts back one value (in this case the product ID), not the ID and the name of the product. You should not need the name since you only need to save the product ID in the database Order table, but if for some reason you need it, then you need to query the database again to get the product name based on the selected ID